# Do I accept an offer from a company that I am not likely to join?

Tags: job-offer

I have a complex situation brewing here and I do not know what to do right now.
I have an offer letter from a company, that I got extended till the 15th of this month, which was termed as my last extension.
Another company, my preferred employer, called me a month back asking about my availability and telling me that they had a position for me. They told me they will get back with an offer by early this month.
Its already 14th and unless they offer me something tomorrow, I have a decision to make tomorrow.
Rejecting an offer before I get one from another company seems too risky a thing to do.
Accepting the offer and later letting it go seems unethical.
Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Your preferred employer is overdue with their offer and you need to follow up NOW. You should have taken them at their word that they would get back to you early in the month with an offer and followed up just after the first week of the month. Absolutely nail them on their offer ASAP and tell them that you are under pressure from the other offer because the extension you got is a final extension.

Comment: If you accept the job, they stop looking and both they and someone who *does* really want that job may be [scrod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrod) when you then turn around and decide you aren't interested after all.  Rude to the company, rude to the other applicants. Yes, you run the risk that someone else accepts the job first... but if its a job you don't want, is that really a problem?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan I am going to do that soon.

Comment: @keshlam I am going to be honest with my employee A. I hope they extend the deadline further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Accepting the offer and later letting it go seems unethical. Can
>   anyone suggest?

That depends on your personal ethics.

Accepting an offer from a company who gave you the courtesy of at least one extension, with the intent that you would likely reject it later isn't something I would do. But perhaps you would.

My thinking would be that if I could get one certain offer, and I felt good about my preferred company, I would be confident that I could reasonably soon get a job from someone (either preferred, or the next company). Thus I would thank that the company for their offer, but move on and not look back.

Perhaps your situation, personal ethics, and self-confidence is different.

Comment: I am an international student, who has to land a job offer to settle in this foreign country. Employer A is good, but not as great as Employer B. What if I turn down Employer A and then something happens at Employer B's end that does not result in an offer(all hypothetical though). In that case I would have to rebegin my job search, which is not easy in a foreign country.
However, I think I am going to say no to offer A, even if offer B does not arrive tomorrow. I just wanted to confirm if I was not being naive. That is what I have been thinking for quite a while myself!

Answer (score 6):

If you have no desire to work for the first company, do not accept their offer. It's that simple.

Accepting an offer from that first company solely because it was the only offer you received is a poor way to manage your career.

> Rejecting an offer before I get one from another company seems too risky a thing to do

Offers from two companies are independent of one another. Don't create a dependency where one doesn't exist. You're allowed to spend a period of time with no open offers in front of you.

Comment: If I had no offer from Company B, I would take Company B handsdown. That's where my dilemma has originated from!